# Некорректное отображение(некоторых) шрифтов в sfml

Tags: c++, шрифты, текст, sfml

Возникла проблема при выводе текста с кириллицей в SFML.
Думал проблема в самом коде, создал отдельный проект для вывода текста, но всё равно у практически всех шрифтов , за исключением одного, не отображается кириллица.

```
#include  <SFML\Graphics.hpp>



using namespace sf;
int main() {
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1056, 736), "SFML test", Style::Close);

    Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
    Text text("", font, 20);
    text.setString("Работает!");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Работает только шрифт CyrilicOld.TTF,но другие шрифты, которые я перепробовал кириллицу тоже поддерживают, пожалуйста подскажите решение этой возникшей ситуации.
Это другие шрифты
[image: Это другие шрифты]
Это CyrilicOld.TTF
[image: Это CyrilicOld.TTF]
Добавил скриншот того, как выглядит строка без L и с ней
[image: Добавил скриншот того, как выглядит строка без L и с ней]

Comment: может кодировка строки неверная?

Comment: @VTT ,Да у меня была такая мысль, но и не смог найти то, как поменять кодировку под utf-16,которую понимает sfml,но тогда кириллица разве не должна вообще не отображаться?

Comment: @V31R под капотом в SFML используется utf-32, а не utf-16. SFML также нормально работает и с utf-8 и с utf-16. Исходник в какой кодировке сохранен?

Comment: @VTT, но на официальном сайте в разделе вопросов написано, что sfml использует utf-16(возможно старая информация), в проекте была включена многобайтовая, я включил юникод, но ничего не случилось, оно не может вывести кириллицу ни на чём кроме того шрифта

Comment: строчка `"Работает!"` не может быть в utf16, это либо utf8 либо windows1251, посмотрите на байты в рантайме ну или используйте `L"Работает"`

Comment: @VTT, а что тогда делать с русским языком?А C++, вообще может понимать unicode?

Comment: @VTT, так в чём может заключаться проблема (почему работает только один шрифт?), L"Работает", выводит только прямоугольники, попытался найти способы перевести всё в нужную кодировку, но ничего то, что бы работало не нашёл

Comment: Попробовал, `L"Работает"` выводит все как надо.

Comment: @VTT, у меня всё равно выводит прямоугольник вместо букв, почему так?И почему работает только 1 шрифт?

Comment: @VTT, я добавил к вопросу скриншот того, как у меня выводится текст без L и с ней

Comment: я попробовал DejaVuSansMono

Comment: VTT, а с ним заработало(я просто пробовал другой шрифт), но так в чём сама проблема?Почему шрифты, которые понимают кириллицу, не все отображаются парвильно?

Comment: @VTT, в любом случае вы помогли найти решение моей проблемы, благодарю